# Are there potential performance penalties for `auto o = SomeType(args)` instead of `SomeType o(args)`?

Tags: c++

I'm a great fan of `auto` and prefer writing `auto o = SomeType(args)`.

It almost always results in calling a constructor only.

@NathanOliver [showed](http://wandbox.org/permlink/KVmWnL9NJ72rJ2fn) that  `-fno-elide-constructors` is capable of turning off copy elision and resulting in a call to a constructor and an assignment operator.

Are there real-world cons of writing `auto o = SomeType(args)`?

Comment: There's no penalties since C++17.  And if you decide to turn on penalties and then get penalties ... 

Comment: That looks like the exact wrong place to use `auto`. If you know the variable is `SomeType` then it looks simpler to use `SomeType    o(args);`

Comment: @M.M Thanks for the answer! Why C++17? What about C++14?

Comment: C++14 you will still get it in simple situations like this (its just not guaranteed by the standard). In C++17 it is guaranteed and a conforming compiler will implement it.

Comment: @MartinYork It is a matter of taste: AAA Style. https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: @NeilButterworth Take a look at https://wandbox.org/permlink/KVmWnL9NJ72rJ2fn

Comment: @Nestor I usually agree with Mr Sutter. But I don't see your use case in that article. The use of `auto` is useful when the type is not explicitly used and the result of expression that is assigned to the variable. That is not the use case above.

Comment: If `args` is actually empty then `Sometype o();` would be a problem, whereas the auto version can be used consistently

Comment: @M.M That was solved: `SomeType o{};`

Comment: @M.M May you please describe potential issues with `SomeType o()`?

Comment: @MartinYork `()` and `{}` can have different behaviour depending on how the class was written

Comment: @Nestor no, comments are not for extended discussion. As you can see the comments are just about people's stylistic opinions

Comment: @Nestor The issue with `SomeType o()` is that it is not a variable declaration but a forward declaration of a function.  See [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: @MartinYork many thanks

Comment: @MartinYork It was solved _long_ before that: `SomeType o;` Those who claim this is a problem are hallucinating

Comment: @MartinYork That is not the most vexing parse. Though it is related.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The second most vexing parse?

Comment: @MartinYork Not a vexing anything, just the wrong kind of declaration ^_^

Comment: _"and an assignment operator"_ Nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of, but no.

Back in the day, and by that I mean pre-C++17, this would be a stylish kind of copy-initialisation. Now by stylish I mean "let's use `auto` for the heck of it", and by copy-initialisation I mean "this is going to use the copy constructor" (or the move constructor, if you have one).

In practice, you were always likely to observe (or, lol, *not* observe) a distinct lack of copy construction (or of move construction), thanks to a beautiful thing called return value optimisation. Ish.

And, since C++17, this is actually guaranteed to produce neither a copy nor a move, thanks to *guaranteed elision*.

However it's still kind of silly. So there you go.

Honestly, just declare your variable normally:

```
SomeType o(args);
```

Your readers, or at least most of them, will thank you.

Bonus (negative) points for `auto main() -> int { /* ... */ }` and yes there are actually people here who insist on that!